# Http get using HttpParams in angular2 returns a 404 error

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

This might be an easy one and I just miss something. I have a GET endpoint and I am trying call it from an Angular UI. I want to send an timestamp to an endpoint as a parameter. I did the basic way:

```typescript
    return this.http.get(this.Uri + academyId + "?dateWhenToCalculate=" + (dateWhenToCompute.getTime() / 1000).toString()).pipe(   
        map((res: Response) => res.json() as Model),
        catchError(this.handleError));
```

Using this I get this URL: http://host/api/route/1?dateWhenToCalculate=1572991200. My endpoint is like:

```typescript
    [HttpGet]
    [GenericAuthorizeFilter]
    [Route("route/{academyId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult ComputePlayerScores(int academyId, string dateWhenToCalculate){....}
```

Using that way of creating the url all is working fine. But when I am trying to do it with HttpParams I keep getting a strange URL and of course an 404 error.

```typescript
    let httpParams = new HttpParams()
        .set('dateWhenToCalculate', (dateWhenToCompute.getTime() / 1000).toString());

    return this.http.get(this.Uri+ academyId, { params: httpParams}).pipe(
        map((res: Response) => res.json() as Model),
        catchError(this.handleError));
```

Using HttpParams I got this

> URL:http://host/api/route/1?updates=%7B%22param%22:%22dateWhenToCalculate%22,%22value%22:%221573423200%22,%22op%22:%22s%22%7D&cloneFrom=%7B%22updates%22:null,%22cloneFrom%22:null,%22encoder%22:%7B%7D,%22map%22:null%7D&encoder=%7B%7D&map=null

Did I miss something?

Comment: 404 comes when the url is not found. Check the spelling once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the minimum amount of code needs to be used for **`HttpParams`**. Here I am using a test api but change that part with your url

In `AppModule` of `app.module.ts` file

```typescript
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ HttpClientModule ],
  ......
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Need following imports first on the component or service:

```typescript
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";
```

Then use `HttpParams` like bellow code:

```typescript
const options =  { params: new HttpParams().set('postId', '1') };
this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments' , options)
    .subscribe((data)=> {console.log(data)});
```

Also you could try with following way instead of `new HttpParams().set('postId', '1')`

```typescript
const options =  { params: new HttpParams({fromString: 'postId=1'}) };
```

Working example is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-optu4f)

---

Following part is not tested by me. I found it from this [link](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-fix-angular-httpclient-not-escaping-url-parameters-ddce3f9b8746). It is kind of a solutions for query parameter was not encoded as expected.

1. Create a class which implements `HttpParameterCodec`. Alternatively,
   you could also extend `HttpUrlEncodingCodec`.
2. The `encodeKey` and `encodeValue` functions need to encode the value.
   Vanilla JavaScript allows you to use `encodeURIComponent`.
3. Use the custom encoder class when creating new `HttpParams: new
   HttpParams({ encoder: new CustomHttpParamEncoder() })`. The important
   part is the usage of `encodeURIComponent`, which is a vanilla
   JavaScript function to encode a string.

---

Custom decoder could looks like:

```typescript
import { HttpParameterCodec } from '@angular/common/http';
export class CustomHttpParamEncoder implements HttpParameterCodec {
  encodeKey(key: string): string {
    return encodeURIComponent(key);
  }
  encodeValue(value: string): string {
    return encodeURIComponent(value);
  }
  decodeKey(key: string): string {
    return decodeURIComponent(key);
  }
  decodeValue(value: string): string {
    return decodeURIComponent(value);
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I still got - 
Request URL: http://evo.test/api/academy/computePlayerScores/1?updates=%7B%22param%22:%22dateWhenToCalculate%22,%22value%22:%221573768800%22,%22op%22:%22s%22%7D&cloneFrom=%7B%22updates%22:null,%22cloneFrom%22:null,%22encoder%22:%7B%7D,%22map%22:null%7D&encoder=%7B%7D&map=null

Which is returns 404

Comment: did you try with the second option?

Comment: also updated the answer with modules those need to be imported

Comment: You were right. The problem was the import that I was using. Instead of :

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

I was using:

import { Http} from '@angular/http';

I was not aware that both of them exists. I will have a look on them. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help you :) . I added some extra info too. Those extra info is not tested by me

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint is `route/{academyId}` but you are calling `http:/host/api/route/endpoint/1` which has the `endpoint` token between `route` and your id. Please remove this `endpoint` token within your http request.

You only have `/` after `http` uri. Please double it.

Comment: I had to change some names and routes to hide some sensitive data and I tried to create a generic URL. Fist part of the URL is correct. Only the part after "..../1?"  differs. I will update the question to avoid the confusion. Thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks for editing. Furthermore you only have 1 `/` after http, pelase double it.